# Move files matching glob in for...done loop returns 'no such file or directory'

Tags: bash, glob, mv

I'm moving files based on their extension.

The following works as expected when there are files matching the glob; but when there are no matching files it returns

> 'mv: rename /Users/xxx/Downloads/*.txt to /Volumes/Internal_HD/*.txt: no such file of directory'

```
in_path=/Users/xxx/Downloads
out_path=/Volumes/Internal_HD

for f in "$in_path"/*.txt; do
    mv -v "$f" "$out_path"
done;
```

['xxx' is the username.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `nullglob` option, otherwise the pattern expands to itself if no files match it:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Comment: Thank you. I guessed it was something straightforward